# Pipe bash stdout only in "debug" mode

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
PIPE=""
if [ $DEBUG = "true" ]; then
    PIPE="2> /dev/null"
fi
git submodule init $PIPE
```

But `$PIPE`gets interpreted as command line args to git. How can I show `stdout` and `stderr` only in debug mode, while piping only `stderr` in non-debug mode?

---

Thanks for great insights. Ended up with doing this, which redirects everything to /dev/null if not in debug mode, and prints both stderr and stdout when in debug mode:

```
# debug mode
if [[ ${DEBUG} = true ]]; then
    PIPE=/dev/stdout
else
    PIPE=/dev/null
fi

git submodule init 2>"${PIPE}" 1>"${PIPE}"
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `$PIPE` in backticks? \`$PIPE\`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, still getting "`line 17: 2>: command not found`"

Comment: What version of bash are you using? Your original code seems to work fine on my Mac version `3.2.57(1)-release`

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`

Comment: And you've tried running just this code above and you get that error? I basically copied and pasted your code and added a single line saying `$DEBUG="true"` and I didn't get any errors about a command not being found...

Comment: That's weird, I get `fatal: /dev/null: '/dev/null' is outside repository` when `PIPE="> /dev/null"` and running `git submodule init $PIPE`

Comment: Have you tried `git submodule init \`eval $PIPE\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using variable after >**

```
if [[ ${DEBUG} = true ]]; then
    errfile=/dev/stderr
else
    errfile=/dev/null
fi

command 2>"${errfile}"
```

**Modifying file descriptors**

You can duplicate the stderr to new file descriptor 3

```
if [[ ${DEBUG} = true ]]; then
    exec 3>&2
else
    exec 3>/dev/null
fi
```

then for each command you want to use new redirection

```
command 2>&3
```

To close fd 3, if no longer needed

```
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to use the $PIPE variable, if possible.

Comment: it's not possible to use redirection '>' inside a variable because the redirection is done before variable expansion, but you can use variable after `>` sign

Comment: So 2> redirects stderr, but how to redirect both stderr and stdout in this way? `2>&1>/dev/null` ?

Comment: This will also work, btw... `if [ "$DEBUG" != "true" ]; then exec 2> /dev/null; fi` You can also short-circuit it with `[ "$DEBUG" == "true" ] || exec 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Yes in fact that was my primary idea but was a bit tired. exec 3>&2 to backup the fd2 then exec 2>/dev/null and finally after commands exec 2>&3 3>&- to restore fd2 and close fd3, but depending on user usage, I though he could use commands with normal fd2 between git commands

Comment: Should be noted that we can also use a sub-shell and redirect fd1 and fd2 once

Answer (score 1):

First i guess you logic is going the wrong way, with DEBUG=true you would be sending stderr to /dev/null. Furthermore your string comparsion is missing the second "=",

How about the simple solution?

```
if [ "${DEBUG}" == "true" ]; then
    git submodule init
else
    git submodule init  2>/dev/null
fi
```

Edit upon your reply:

Alternatively you could use `eval`, but be careful it's considered evil ;)

```
if [ "${DEBUG}" == "true" ]; then
    PIPE=""
else
    PIPE="2>/dev/null" 
fi 
eval git submodule init $PIPE
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, but I have a long list of functions, which is why I'd like to have the $PIPE.